# Unknown User Permission(s): ManageSandboxes & ViewPlatformEvents

Tags: profile

I am trying to deploy using ANT from one sandbox A to other sandbox B.

The profiles are failing on the deployment with following error.

```
system admin profile: unknown user permission: Managesandboxes
custom profile: unknown user permission: viewplatformevents
```

When I logged into both the sandboxes A & B, I could see the two system permissions from the error, exists in source A but not in target B.

Those permissions exist in prod as well and the source B is refreshed recently from prod.

Is this usual or what might cause these issues.

And if i migrate it to prod from our current target org B, will the existing permission in prod turn to false as it doesn't exist in B  or its not effected as its not referenced anywhere.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? We are still experiencing the issue.

Comment: We addressed the issue with some manual work didn't find a real solution when it occurred.

Comment: we also have a manual work around, problem is that half of our team forgets to do it :)

Answer (score 2):

My source and target environment were on the same version so to solve similar issue I clicked "Match Production Licenses" on source and target. Please verify.

Comment: where did you see this "Match Production Licenses"?

Comment: Go to Setup->Company Profile->Company Information and at the top of the page you will find Match Production Licenses

Comment: +1 - saved my bacon here for `ViewPlatformEvents` which I think is associated with Shield Event Monitoring that wasn't enabled in one of the orgs in the deployment pipeline

Answer (score 1):

Most often when I see these "unknown user permission" type errors, it's because either

1. The version indicated in the package.xml doesn't support the feature, or
2. The source environment is on a newer API version than the target, and it's supported in the former and not the latter.