# Error: Unknown user permission: ViewPlatformEvents

Tags: deployment, ant

How do I get this permission in my sandbox?
It's causing errors in Jenkins deployments because it exists in all our developer sandboxes, but not in the developer pro sandbox where we are all integrating our changes into.

I found this question below, but the answers are not very satisfying (not helping me)
[Unknown User Permission(s): ManageSandboxes & ViewPlatformEvents](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/135531/unknown-user-permissions-managesandboxes-viewplatformevents)

All sandboxes have the same API version, the same packages installed, don't have any platform events configured.

Comment: This may not be applicable for your case, but I spend a lot of time, trying to deal with similar thing. In the end, I wrote a custom script, that wipe some  (rare and not touched) user permissions from admin profile, committed that source code and forgot about that. That may be useful for your case as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable Forensics permission on Event Monitoring setting
This solved the issue for us